# jquery - call function to return json string within event declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using a plugin called MapSVG, and am making an events calendar to run alongside it, the countries on the map being highlighted if there are events inside them with a tooltip for small information - on click, the countries display further information in a panel on right hand side.
The problem lies in gathering data from the SQL database, and passing that data to the plugin. This is what I have tried so far..

I have a function which runs through the SQL/JSON array matching events to the country they are in, creating a string which is understood by the MapSVG plugin:

```
function regions(data) {
  var region_array = 'regions: {';

  $.each(data['regions'], function( i, v ) {
    region_array = region_array + i + ': { tooltip: "' + v['events'] + ' events in ' + data[i]['details']['name'] + '", attr:{fill: "#e58271"} },';
  });
  region_array = region_array.slice(0, -1) + '}';
  return region_array;
}
```

Which returns a string:

```
regions: 
{
gb: { tooltip: "1 events in England", attr:{fill: "#e58271"} },
fr: { tooltip: "2 events in France", attr:{fill: "#e58271"} },
de: { tooltip: "1 events in Germany", attr:{fill: "#e58271"} },
at: { tooltip: "6 events in Austria", attr:{fill: "#e58271"} }
}
```

This string works correctly when copied into MapSVG directly, however I need it to run dynamically, and change depending on events being added/removed/edited/extended.

So, I had thought that running the function within the mapSvg event/declaration would work, however i've just ran into problems..

```
$('#mapsvg-other').mapSvg({
  source : 'maps/europe.svg',
  colors: {background: '#CBECF3', base: '#eeaba0', stroke: "#CBECF3", selected: '#d42e12', hover: '#d42e12'},
  regions: {labels: {attr: {fill: '#555555'}}},
  width: '450px',
  height: '450px',
  tooltipsMode: 'custom',
  cursor: 'pointer',


  onClick: function(e,m){

  },
  /* regions goes into here, regions(data) or + regions(data) + will not work, is there a way to do this? */     
});
```

Is there any way to insert this information properly? Or would I have to generate an array with each regions info and call individually? (Seems a bit of a worse workaround as it means slightly more long-winded code, so in the quest of ever-increasing efficiency and tidyness, it'd be nice to have this work!)

Comment: Is PHP an option? Then you could generate the needed string dynamically.

Comment: Don’t have your function build a string then, but the correct JavaScript data structure directly. (Or use JSON.decode on the string – but that would be quite a nonsense, building a string in the first place only to convert it to a data structure afterwards …)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I would use it if I could but this page is to be included onto a clients website which has quite stringent rules/regs =/
All PHP is done on our server and requested via an AJAX call to load into the map.

Comment: I think i may understand what you're suggesting CBroe, the only work around i can think is to list the regions individually, then create an array with each regions details (or lack of details - annoyingly) and then call each set of details on load..

It's a viable solution, just not the nicest one! haha, I would've thought i could call a function to return a string within an event :s maybe not though!